# Align the contents of a numerical matrix when you have minus signs

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

I have a matrix that looks like

[image]

```
\begin{equation*}  
  \left [\begin{array}{cccccc}  
    0 & 0 & 6 & -6 & 0 & 0 \\  
    0 & 0 & -6 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\  
    0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 5 & -5 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -5 & 5   
\end{array} \right ]  \end{equation*}
```

How should I sort of align this matrix to make it more symmetrical looking and without the disgusting slight shift due to the negative sign?

Comment: Take a look at the `bmatrix*` environment from `mathtools`.

Answer (score 12):

The `mathtools` package extends `amsmath`, among other things, with the `matrix*` environments, which can take an optional argument for the  alignment of their columns (`c` by default).

I added another solution, for which all columns have the same width, with the `\mathllap` command (also from `mathtools`):

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    0 & 0 & 6 & -6 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & -6 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & -5 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -5 & 5
\end{bmatrix*}
 \end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}\setlength{\arraycolsep}{6pt}
  \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    0 & 0 & 6 & \mathllap{-}6 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \mathllap{-}6 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & \mathllap{-}5 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\mathllap{-}5 & 5
\end{bmatrix*}
 \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

In case there is a minus sign in the first column, it results in a dissymmetry for the spacing of the left and right delimiters, which may look unpleasant to the eye. To make it acceptable, one may add a small space at the end of each row of the matrix, like this:

```
\begin{equation*}\setlength{\arraycolsep}{6pt}
  \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    0 & 0 & 6 & \mathllap{-}6 & 0 & 0\enspace \\
    -0 & 0 & \mathllap{-}6 & 6 & 0 & 0\enspace \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & \mathllap{-}5\enspace \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\mathllap{-}5 & 5\enspace 
\end{bmatrix*}
 \end{equation*}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add an example showing a matrix with a negative value in the first column.

Comment: @Barbara Beeton:: That's a challenge! It will destroy symmetry  in spacings of  left and right bracket. However one can add `\;` ate the end of each row to make it acceptable – at least from my point of view.

Comment: Yes.  That's why (nitpicker that I am) I suggested it.  Thought it would be better if shown here, so that an unwary user wouldn't be caught unaware.  I agree with your caveat concerning the spacing at the right.

Comment: Your wish is my command, Milady! Does it befit you?

Comment: Very nice indeed, both comment and visual.  Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You can change column specifiers from `c` to `r` and you will obtain:

[image]

Is this what you looking for? MWE for above matrix is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\left[\begin{array}{*{6}{r}}
    0 & 0 &  6 & -6 &  0 &  0 \\
    0 & 0 & -6 &  6 &  0 &  0 \\
    0 & 0 &  0 &  0 &  5 & -5 \\
    0 & 0 &  0 &  0 & -5 &  5
\end{array} \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Approved: this was the last vote I had available.

Comment: @Sebastiano, than you very much! You are very enthusiastic voter ;-)

Comment: Thank you! Very much!

Answer (score 5):

Here there is my proposal. You could to use (for example but there are several strategies) [`spalign`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spalign)  package with has the same approach to build a matrix or array to have minus signs aligned. Here there is a screenshot and a MWE.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spalign}
\begin{document}
\[ \spaligndelims{[}{]}\spalignmat[r]{0 0 6 -6 0 0; 0  0  -6  6  0  0; 0  0  0   0  5  -5; 0  0  0  0  -5  5} \]
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM:** Using `nicematrix` versions 5.0 where the option `r` aligns all the columns rightwards, you can obtained the same result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{pNiceMatrix}[r,margin]
0 & 0 & 6 & -6 & 0 & 0 \\  
0 & 0 & -6 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\  
0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 5 & -5 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -5 & 5  
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 ... interesting package `spalign`! So far I didn't aware about it.

Comment: @Zarko I'm specializing in finding new packages that are very little used but are beautiful and efficacious.